# Android OpenGL ES2.0, shader compile false on some devices

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

From firebase logs, i can see that around 1% of my app users got the shader compilation error.

I read the source code and have no idea why it's not working on some device.

This is the vertex shader.

```
precision mediump float; 
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;  
attribute vec4 vPosition;  
varying vec2 textureCoordinate;  
void main() {   
    textureCoordinate=vec2((1.0+vPosition.x)/2.0, (1.0-vPosition.y)/2.0); 
    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;  
}
```

This is the Fragment shader.

```
    precision mediump float;  
varying vec2 textureCoordinate;  
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;  
uniform float flipH;  
uniform float flipV;  
uniform float angle;  
uniform float blendAlpha; 
uniform vec4 sampleCoord1;  
uniform vec4 sampleCoord2;  
uniform float blurV;  
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture1; //frame   
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;   
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture3;   
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture4;   
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture5;   
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture6;   
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture7;   
uniform float fW;  //sample proportionally   
uniform float fH;   
uniform float sX; // start of x and y.   
uniform float sY;   
vec3 texel;   
uniform float iGlobalTime; //for video   
uniform float alpha;  

vec3 effect(vec3 texel){ 
    return texel; 
} 

vec2 cllCoord1(float s, float t){
    return vec2(sampleCoord1.x + s*sampleCoord1.z, sampleCoord1.y + t*sampleCoord1.w);
} 
vec2 cllCoord2(float s, float t){
    return vec2(sampleCoord2.x + s*sampleCoord2.z, sampleCoord2.y + t*sampleCoord2.w);
} 

void main() {  
    float s=textureCoordinate.x; 
    float t=textureCoordinate.y; 
    vec3 srcTexel = texture2D(inputImageTexture1, cllCoord1(s,t)).rgb; 
    vec3 desTexel = texture2D(inputImageTexture7, cllCoord2(s,t)).rgb; 
    if( s <= blendAlpha ){  
        desTexel = texture2D(inputImageTexture7, cllCoord2(1.0 + s -blendAlpha, t)).rgb; 
    }else{ 
        desTexel = vec3(0.0); 
    } 

    if(length(textureCoordinate-vec2(0.0, 1.0))>= blendAlpha*1.42){      
        texel=srcTexel; 
    }else{      
        texel=desTexel; 
    } 

    texel=effect(texel); 
    gl_FragColor= vec4(texel, alpha);  
}
```

After compiling, the compileStatus[0] is false.

```
    final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

    if (compileStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
```

I try to analyze the shader above, but i don't have any idea, why it's not working on some devices. In my own devices/emulators, it's always working fine!.

It should not be compilation error, otherwise i will got more detailed log like which line is not compiling.

Comment: Use [`GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader)`](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.opengl.GLES20&method=glGetShaderInfoLog) to get the error message.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Hi actually I added, but it returned empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's as low as 1% of users failing then you're probably in the realms of driver bugs. It's often useful to run code through the GLSL reference compiler to confirm that, but I strongly suspect that's the case: [glslang](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/Reference-Compiler/).

If I had to guess what you've done that's confusing a non-compliant compiler, I'd go for:

1. A var called `texel` is used as both a global variable and a function parameter.
2. You have 6 unused samplers
3. You have a call to `texture2D` which can be skipped by an `if` statement. This is undefined behaviour if there are mipmaps.

> Accessing mip-mapped textures within the body of a non-uniform
>   conditional block gives an undefined value.  A non-uniform conditional
>   block is a block whose execution cannot be determined at compile time.

Comment: Hi @Columbo, thanks a lot, your answer is very useful!